# wp_get_theme Warning: Illegal offset type

Tags: plugin-development, functions, deprecation

I'm using `Post templates` plugin.  But its very outdated.

I'm getting `Warning: Illegal offset type` at this line

```
$templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
```

Here is my full function code.

```
function get_post_templates() {
    $themes = wp_get_themes();
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
    $post_templates = array();

    $base = array(trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()));

    foreach ((array)$templates as $template) {
        $template = WP_CONTENT_DIR . str_replace(WP_CONTENT_DIR, '', $template); 
        $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);

        // don't allow template files in subdirectories
        if (false !== strpos($basename, '/'))
            continue;

        $template_data = implode('', file( $template ));

        $name = '';
        if (preg_match( '|Single Post Template:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name))
            $name = _cleanup_header_comment($name[1]);

        if (!empty($name)) {
            if(basename($template) != basename(__FILE__))
                $post_templates[trim($name)] = $basename;
        }
    }

    return $post_templates;

}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Line

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();
```

returns a `WP_Theme` Object, and you cannot use an Object in an `Array` like this.

Use

```
$templates = $themes[$theme->template]['Template Files'];
```

To get the `Array` of your template Files. In Order to get this function running again, you also have to change `Single Post Template` to `Template Name`:

```
if (preg_match( '|Template Name:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name))
```

As you did not specify what you want to do with the results, I can't help you any further, but you should be okay this way for this function.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_get_theme()` returns an object. An object cannot be a key for an array.

Use `$theme->get_stylesheet()` for the key if you want to get the templates from the child theme and `$theme->get_template()` if you want the files from the parent theme.